# Linq List returning duplicate data instead of multiple datasets

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have some linq to return a list of barcodes:

```
var barcodeList = context.table1.Where(z => z.register == registerNo).Select(z => z.barcode).ToList();
```

I'm then trying to retrieve the data associated with each barcode:

```
var info = context.table2.Where(z => barcodeList.Contains(z.barcode)).ToList();
```

***barcodeList*** is returning 12 unique barcodes.
However, ***info*** is returning data associated with the first barcode 12x.

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: Your code looks like it would work. Are you sure the barcodes from table1 match those in table2? Make sure there are no hidden characters behind your barcodes. For example: if you copy data from Excel, sometimes you also copy the new line break.

Comment: @RikMaton I've added a .Trim the the barcode to be sure. Still happening. And the barcodes match in both tables.

Comment: Have you tried running a comparable query in SQL, to see what the result would be? `select barcode from table2 where barcode in (select barcode from table1 where register = 1)` Use the same register as you were using in your example.

Comment: var barcodeList = context.table1.Where(z => z.register == registerNo).GroupBy(z => z.barcode).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng so the barcodelist has the issue? Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: You are using Entity where there is a mapping file that associates the c# classes with the database.  You have two different tables (classes) in the database base 1) context.table1 2) context.table2.   Context implies Entity. When a database get changes (tables and columns) that mapping also has to get refresh so the classes are consistent with the database.  I think the issue is actually how the method "Contains" and "Where" is working.  Contains is doing a search of the data in the object and Where is using IEquality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity models were pulling from visual foxpro tables which, probably due to the technology being old, brought some quirks with it. I just deleted the referenced tables within the model and re-implemented them and my code worked (after some alterations).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your query does not work correctly, but what you're doing looks like a join:

```
var query = from barcode in context.Table1
            join info in context.Table2 on barcode.barcode equals info.barcode
            where barcode.register == registerNo
            select info;
```